# Javascript calculator addition is not working properly

Tags: javascript, function, math

Here is my really basic Javascript calculator code. Except for the addition symbol,  my calculator is just working fine. However, addition is not doing its job: instead it combines them. How to fix it?

```
var first = prompt("First number");
var second = prompt("Second number");
parseInt(first);
parseInt(second);
var islem = prompt("Is it +/-/* or /?");
if (islem == "+" ) {
    document.write(first + second);
}
else if ( islem == "-") {
    document.write(first - second);
}
else if ( islem == "*" ) {
    document.write(first * second);
}
else {
    document.write(first / second);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an integer.**

You have to assign `parsed` value to your variable, like this:

```
first=parseInt(first);
second=parseInt(second);
```

Or simply,

```
document.write(parseInt(first)+parseInt(second));
```

See reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```js
var first = prompt("First number");
var second = prompt("Second number");
parseInt(first);
parseInt(second);
var islem = prompt("Is it +/-/* or /?");
if (islem == "+" ) {
    document.write(parseInt(first)+parseInt(second));
}
else if ( islem == "-") {
    document.write(first-second);
}
else if ( islem == "*" ) {
    document.write(first*second);
}
else {
    document.write(first/second);
}
```

Comment: Because you have to `convert` to `number` every `prompt` result which is a `string`.

Comment: But the OP is already calling `parseInt()`, so rather than add another call to it, just capture the result the first time.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, sorry. my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `parseInt()`, you need to capture the returned value so that you can use that number going forward.  Right now, you are calling `parseInt()` and not doing anything with the returned value, so it is lost immediately.

It is also advisable to use the optional second parameter to `parseInt()`, which is the radix value that sets the base of the number you are working with. Typically, you'll want that to be `10` when working with base 10 numbers. This is really important because if the string you are working with starts with a `0` and you don't supply the radix, the operation will assume you are working with an octal value and if the string were to start with `0x`, then the operation will assume you are working with a hex (base 16) value.

See more about using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

The code should be:

```
var first = prompt("First number");
var second = prompt("Second number");
first = parseInt(first, 10);
second = parseInt(second, 10);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not storing the `parseInt` result anywhere, and instead performing operations on strings. **Since `+` is also a string concatenation operation,**  you get the concatenated string as a result. Try changing lines 3-4 to:

```
first = parseInt(first, 10); //don't forget the base!
second = parseInt(second, 10);
//TBD: add some error handling code to check values
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the right program:

```
var first = prompt("First number");
var second = prompt("Second number");
var firstParsedInteger = parseInt(first);
var secondParsedInteger = parseInt(second);
var islem = prompt("Is it +/-/* or /?");
if (islem == "+" ) {
    document.write(firstParsedInteger + secondParsedInteger);
}
else if ( islem == "-") {
    document.write(first-second);
}
else if ( islem == "*" ) {
    document.write(first*second);
}
else {
    document.write(first/second);
}
```

Note: You were never using the parsed value. In javascript, if   you are using var for numbers and using '+' operator. this treats those numbers as string not as a number. Remember to parse integer when playing with var and + in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

These answers are all great! I'd go one step further and

1) Call `parseInt()` on the prompts immediately, so that you're not declaring as many unnecessary variables

2)  Use a switch statement instead of an if/else! It'll make it easier to add other cases, for exponentiation, etc. This one's more of a style choice, though :)

3) You can also consider using `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()` so that it can handle decimal inputs!

```
var first = parseInt(prompt("First number"));
var second = parseInt(prompt("Second number"));
var islem = prompt("Is it +/-/* or /?");
switch (islem) {
    case "+":
        document.write(first+second);
        break;
    case "-":
        document.write(first-second);
        break;
    case "*":
        document.write(first*second);
        break;
    case "/":
        document.write(first/second);
        break;
    default:
        document.write("Excuse me? Give me an operator, please!");
};
```